# What does the error "error setting the index on collection" mean?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to set up a login page using express, mongoose, and mongodb, written using nodes.js, and I'm getting this error.  It seems to comes from the connect-mongo version: 0.8.2 module.

> Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions

I have a database in mongodb named `myapp`. Should the `sessions` collection exist in the `myapp` database?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698661/mongodb-error-setting-ttl-index-on-collection-sessions

Comment: Re-organized question to make it flow better; fixed grammar.  Removed natter.  There seem to be several deductions in this question: "seems to come from the connect-mongo module", and "[s]hould the sessions collection exist in the myapp database?".  It's not 100% clear what debugging work went into drawing those conclusions, which it might be good to add to this question.